# combine multiple yaml files with indentation in python

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have below directory and file structure. I want to create one yaml file out of all the yaml files within these below folders.

```
[root@localhost test]# tree
.
├── group_vars
│   └── all.template
├── host_vars
│   └── host.template
└── vars
    ├── CASSANDRA
    ├── CQLSH
    ├── CSYNC2
    ├── DSE_OPSCENTER
    ├── DSE_OPSCENTER_AGENT
    ├── logging.template
    ├── packages_vars.template
    ├── UDM
    └── user_pub_keys
```

Result could be (Example yaml file)

```
group_vars/all.template:
    <all the all.template data at this indentation>
host_vars/host.template:
    <all the host.template data at this indentation>
vars/CASSANDRA:
    <all the CASSANDRA data at this indentation>
vars/CQLSH:
    <all the CQLSH data at this indentation>
... so  on
```

I can join these files within the folders but I don't know how I can bring the format of yaml that I described above.

What I tried?

I got the idea of writing to the file `<folder_name>/file_name>` and then give 4 spaces and write the content as it is.

Something like below

```
with open(actual_path) as i: # actual path is just the path to the file
    outfile.write('vars#'+fname) # vars is the folder name and fname is the file name. # is just any separator for the file
    outfile.write(i.read()) # here I can add 4 spaces 
    outfile.write('\n')
```

Is this a good way to create the yaml file the way I want? If so, I just need to know how I can start writing file (as it is) after the 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just dump the content of a file into a YAML document (or documents), as on loading that content will get parsed. Such parsed content might be incorrect YAML, causing a loader error, or it might be correct YAML resulting in a data structure that is unlikely going to be turned exactly into the (string) content of the original file read. The latter because a YAML dumper normalizes indentation and most dumpers dispose of end-of-line comments.

Files can also consist of binary data and that needs to be properly encoded, or, depending on the content of the file, escaped.

Then the approach to put a `#` (as in your code) as a separator between path elements and filenames is not going to work if any of the paths or files has that valid filename character in their name. You should either use a reserved character (on Unix-likes the NUL character or `/`), or make things more transportable by splitting the path into segments and putting those segments plus the filename in a sequence of string scalars.

To get all that to be correct YAML, make sure you load this information in a datastructure and then dump that datastructure using a YAML loader/dumper library instead of trying to write the file yourself. With Python your only real choice is `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package) as e.g. the older PyYAML cannot dump a sequence as a key for a mapping, although that is perfectly valid according to the YAML specification.

There are multiple ways to create the datastructure and you also need to decide if your file is going to contain one YAML document or multiple ones.
If you want one document, I would represent the path+filename separated by the `/`, as a key into mapping and have the content of the files in literal block scalars form as values for those keys:

```
import os
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

root_dir = '.'

data = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()

for root, directory_names, file_names in os.walk(root_dir):
    if root == root_dir:
        # don't do the file in the current directory, only the ones in subdirs
        continue
    # this makes a list after removing the root_dir
    rsplit = root.replace(root_dir + os.sep, '', 1).split(os.sep)
    for file_name in file_names:
        # open as binary
        with open(os.path.join(root, file_name), 'rb') as fp:
            raw_content = fp.read()
        # then if conversion to unicode fails, keep as binary
        try:
            content = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.PreservedScalarString(raw_content.decode('utf-8'))
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            content = raw_content
        # in the next line join the segments using '/', don't use os.sep, as you might
        # not be on Unix/Linux
        data['/'.join(rsplit + [file_name])] = content

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
host_vars/host.template: |+
  this is the content of the file 
  host.template it has two empty lines at the end


group_vars/all.template: |
  this is the content of the
  file all.template
vars/CASSANDRA: !!binary |
  jA0EAwMCeujy0iby+oFgyUiXUDg2VWaphMZSwDxIIyo0h/aVkrmVaRJy7DFjLhfNrKZL9wRiztvL
  slM0cA/N1jDZ2DJCT5317mlTNuWZCoj/8EzvPegpi7w=
```

A few things to note in addition to the comments in the program:

1. The CASSANDRA file was on purpose made binary (a gpg encoding with the filename as key of multiple times the content of the file `all.template`). Nothing special needs to be done to get the `!!binary` tag.
2. `host.template` has two empty lines at the end, therefor YAML dumps this automatically with `|+`
3. on reading the file, if portability is important, make sure you reconstruct the path + filename by splitting using `/` then combining using `os.sep`.

Comment: with your last line, I dumped data to the file with open('config.yaml', 'w') as file:
    yaml.dump(data, file)

Comment: Yes that is the way to do that, while testing I usually write to `stdout`, so I can see what is happening (i.e. whether my assumptions are correct).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the better option to have a valid YAML file as output is to use [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), so you can read all the YAML files, combine them in memory and then dump the resulting object to a new file.